# Error with this code? [C]

Tags: c

I'm supposed to modify a code `repdigit.c` so that the user can enter more than one number to be tested for a repeated digit. For some reason though all my compiler says is `No repeated digit`, no matter what number I input.

```
int main(void)
{
    bool digit_seen[10] = {false};
    int digit;
    long n, m;

    while (1)
    { 
        printf("Enter a number (0 to terminate): ");
        scanf("%ld", &n);

        if (n == 0)
            break;

        n = m;

        while (m > 0) 
        {
            digit = m % 10;
            if (digit_seen[digit])
                break;
            digit_seen[digit] = true;
            m /= 10;
        }

        if (m > 0)
            printf("Repeated digit\n");
        else
            printf("No repeated digit\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You should post that comment somewhere(with the links) so I can use this on StackOverflow on a daily basis.

Comment: Pretty sad that we have to type out the stuff that's already on the "how to post" page

Comment: @JaredBurrows: I vary the pasted content on occasion to suit the context — this was one such.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Haha. Wow thanks! I'll use this to help clarify asking questions for new users.

Comment: I've rolled back to the original question  (another editor edited to remove the "answered" comment from OP but left in the code correction)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with `n=m`. Since `m` is not initialized, it will contain some garbage value. You probably wanted to have `m=n`.

Comment: but in the code I have it break out of that loop before hand if there is a repeated digit with: `if (digit_seen[digit])`

Comment: @NicolasDiken , You are correct. Just use `m=n;` instead of `n=m;` the code will work.

Comment: Edited : Then the problem is with n=m. Since m is not initialised, it will contain some garbage value. You probably wanted to have m=n.

Answer (score 3):

1. `m` is not initialized;
2. You are reading `n` and copying `m` to `n`; `m` might contain garbage value.

   ```
   n=m;
   ```

   Solution: Change `n=m;` to `m=n;`

Comment: even with that fix (which I cant believe I messed up with lol..) It constantly say's `Repeated digit` and never says `No repeated digit`